# 'Require is not defined' in Netbeans - Javascript

Tags: javascript, netbeans, npm, require

I am new to Javascript and am interested in using a library from github. I am using netbeans to code and I have installed node.js. However, I am still getting the error 'Require is not defined'. I have installed 'browserify' as this seemed like a common solution, but I am still getting this error.
Am I doing something wrong?

[Image of set up libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYeN5.png)

**Update**
I have also found that there is a problem with one of my libraries, think it could be relevant to the original problem.

[Problem with library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdWMA.png)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is because require() does not exist in the browser/client-side JavaScript.Can you  give it a try to following statements;

1. Use `<script>` tag.
2. Use a CommmonJS implementation. Synchronous
   dependencies like Node.js
3. Use an AMD implementation.

And keep library codes and application codes seperated. ( bundle.js and script.js  )

Browserify will take all the script files necessary and put them into the "bundle.js" file, so you should only have to include "bundle.js" in the HTML file, not the "script.js" file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing NodeJS based project, you should use NodeJS project type in NetBeans where require() is considered as known global function and as such NetBeans won't show the hint.You can change your current project to enable NodeJS support by right clicking on the project, select Project Properties -> NodeJS and check Enable NodeJS support.

If you are using RequireJS library, you can also enable RequireJS support in Project Properties in JavaScript Frameworks -> RequireJS

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still getting the same error. Is there anything I need to include in my code to make this work?

Comment: Could you attach screenshot of the issue? Generally speaking having the JS file (in which some unknown global variable is declared) in Site Root should help. You don't need to include it in html file  using script element. But even then it depends on how the particular JS library exposes the global variable, not all patterns can be "understood" by NetBeans

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't add any more links due to restrictions from stack overflow.

**Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined (17:23:07:161 | error, javascript)
    at (anonymous function) (public_html/index.html:22:18)**

That is the error I am getting, I have included the other problem in the post above.


**var sentiment = require('sentiment');** 

This is the code I am trying to use.